# Adding a column header to an output table in R

Tags: r

I'm learning R and this is probably a very simple question but for some reason I'm not able to find a previous post applying to my case.

I'm using a funcion in R creating an output table having one single column with no header:

```
> resp41365_pred413561 = predict(xtree,resp41365,type="class")
> head(resp41365_pred413561)
             1              2              3              4              5              6 
Feeding/Moving Feeding/Moving Moving/Feeding Feeding/Moving Moving/Feeding Moving/Feeding 
Levels: Feeding/Moving Moving/Feeding Standing
```

And would like to add a header `predicted` to this single column table.

I've tried things like:

```
> colnames(resp41365_pred413561) <- c("predicted")
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "predicted") : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Update:

My table happened to be a vector. The problem got solved by using:

```
resp41365_pred413561<-data.frame(resp41365_pred413561)
colnames(resp41365_pred413561) <- c("predicted")
```

Comment: What is the output of `dim(resp41365_pred413561)` and `class(resp41365_pred413561)`

Comment: `colnames(resp41365_pred413561) <- c(colnames(resp41365_pred413561), "predicted")` does it work?

Comment: @storaged I get: ```> colnames(resp41365_pred413561) <- c(colnames(resp41365_pred413561), "predicted")
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "predicted") : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions```

Comment: @Sonny It's: ```> dim(resp41365_pred413561)
NULL
> class(resp41365_pred413561)
[1] "factor"``` Does this help?

Comment: `attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions` told you what you want. To confirm try `colnames(iris[,1])<-c('a')`

Comment: It means resp41365_pred413561 is one dimension, co it cannot have colnames set

Comment: Try: `names(resp41365_pred413561)="predicted"`

Comment: @A.Suliman I have: ```> colnames(resp41365_pred413561[,1])<-c("predicted")
Error in `[.default`(`*tmp*`, , 1) : incorrect number of dimensions```

Comment: `predict` returns an object based on the class of its argument. Maybe resp41365... is a vector. Vectors do not have colnames. You could transform it to a dataframe and then set the colname

Comment: @tushaR I get no error message but I don't get a header. Just the same table as it nothing had happened.

Comment: The print of predicted that you showed does not look like either a  table or a data frame, it looks like a vector.  Table and column have specific meanings in R but you are using the regular English meaning.  Also "header" is not a concept in R.  Do you mean a name?  Do you want to change your vector to a data frame?

Comment: @juansalix I meant it's not possible i.e. not possible to set name for "on an object with less than two dimensions". So to solve your probelm try `resp41365_pred413561<-data.frame(resp41365_pred413561);colnames(resp41365_pred413561) <- c("predicted") `

Comment: `names(resp41365_pred413561) <- "predicted"` should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overcome error:"attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimension" in xts object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010213/how-to-overcome-errorattempt-to-set-colnames-on-an-object-with-less-than-two)

Comment: @A.Suliman Thanks that worked!!